# Easily convert an Android app to Windows Phone

Tags: gratis, android, windows-phone, emulator, code-conversion

I maintain a Android app. It does not use any framework, 100% pure [native Android](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/27568/native-mobile-app) (Java, with [the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk). No HTML5, no cross-platform layer such as MonoTouch/Titanium/etc). It does not use any third-party library nor proprietary libraries like [Play Services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/open-source-implementation-of-google-play-services). Also, no NDK calls.

While Windows Phone is a very narrow market segment, I would like to port my Android app to Windows Phone, if it is easy.

**QUESTION:** What is the easiest way to port my Android app to Windows Phone?

Absolute requirements:

- Free
- No need to buy/borrow a Windows Phone (not many people have one)
- The easier the better

Ideally:

- Runs on Linux
- Ideally zero code/configuration to write, everything is guessed
- Ideally runnable with just a command line

Answer (score 2):

By pure Android I presume that your application is written in one, (or more), of C/C++/C#/Java/HTML5 - Android is the OS not the language.

Microsoft do supply a free community edition of Visual Studio [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads)

- Free **Yes**
- Will guess how to convert from Android OS to Windows *It is from Microsoft so I very much doubt it.*
- Includes Windows Phone Emulators **Yes**
- Run on Linux *It is from Microsoft - "Nobody Uses Linux, What is Linux?"*
- Run from the command line *It is from Microsoft - "Why would anybody run anything from the command line?"*

All that said it is possible to put conditional compilation, wrappers and macros in place so that a single code base will run on both but don't expect MS to make it easy and you may find that if there are any traces of Android stuff in code submitted for the MS App store it gets short shift *but maybe that is just me being pessimistic/cynical!*

#### Update

I did check and Visual Studio Community 2013 **claims** to offer the ability to develop for Android & IOS as well as Windows phone.

Comment: By "pure Android" I mean Java with the Android SDK, as opposed to HTML5. I add a few details to make the question less ambiguous.

Comment: Microsoft is touting its willingness to change: https://www.theverge.com/2015/4/29/8511439/microsoft-windows-10-android-ios-apps-bridges I hope it will eventually bring some tools like what my question asks for :-)

Comment: Just wanted to say that. MS started to put out x-platform tools. And they want to push their Wphone stuff, trying to lure in Android devs. So though I'm not a lover of MS at all, except for the last item (command-line) I no longer can share your doubts ;) Even CLI I'm no longer sure (why else do they push Powershell so much?).

Comment: But I noticed that the web site makes no mention of tools that run on anything other than Win 8.1 Pro and in the past when they have released any cross platform tools they were well hidden and required installing proprietary components....